# Why were many of my answers upvoted in a short time?

Tags: support, upvotes, daily-reputation-limit

I don't want to complain, but today 22 of my answers received an upvote in a short amount of time (less than an hour), gaining me 200 reputation and a bronze badge for hitting the daily reputation limit.

Some of the answers were more recent, some were a few years old. I didn't notice an obvious pattern.

I find this very unusual. Was this caused by a bug or some recalculation of votes, or am I the "victim" of serial upvoting? Do I have to expect that this is reversed and I lose the reputation and the badge again?

Comment: *Do I have to expect that this is reversed and I lose the reputation and the badge again?* --> yes unfortunately .. seems like some wanted to *thank you*

Comment: Just the reps, badges aren't revoked.

Comment: You are unlikely [to lose the mortarboard badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126363).

Comment: I've dealt with this specific account; there were other issues that needed addressing. The votes will be removed shortly.

Comment: If you merge your account with another account, you may lose the badge. If I understand the process correctly, all badges are recalculated on a merge.